# Istio EnvoyProxy Access Logs - how to log external HTTPS calls?

Tags: azure-aks, istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

I have ISTIO service mesh configured in my AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service) cluster.

I am able to see the access logs of requests my services makes to other services within the AKS cluster.

However, When my service makes a call to external services, the call is not logged in the ISTIO-PROXY (ENVOY)'s access Log.

For example, call to readme of prometheus from inside my service container:

```
curl -kv https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus/prometheus/main/README.md
```

All I can see from the istio-proxy is this -

```
[2022-09-05T14:18:38.038Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 879 12246 45 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "185.199.108.133:443" PassthroughCluster x.x.x.x:39380 185.199.108.133:443 x.x.x.x:39378 - -
```

185.199.108.133 is the github's IP. How can I get the response code, path and other details of the call?

I'm using the default access log format of Envoy as described here - https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/

Comment: did you find a solution ?  i am in a similar boat

Comment: The cause is that the istio-proxy sidecars can't intercept HTTPS traffic - there's no TLS termination there. The solution will be to have a TLS termination at the istio-proxy layer but I doubt there is support for this in istio yet.